# Vimeo fullscreen size

Tags: css, wordpress, vimeo

I have a question about vimeo fullscreen size. I using wordpress and i want to do that when i press a link and it shows fullscreen.
for example my code:

```
 <a class="hovermask"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-portfolio-<?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", $field['title']); ?>"><span><?php echo $field['title']; ?></span></a>
```

AND This is vimeo iframe:

```
 <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/99628364?color=fcfeff" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match up to your question?

Comment: Vimeo has a set of HTTP and JS APIs, maybe you can find something there: http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Answer (score 1):

To display a Vimeo video fullscreen add this css to your iframe:

```
iframe{
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       border: 0px;
       border-image-source: initial;
       border-image-slice: initial;
       border-image-width: initial;
       border-image-outset: initial;
       border-image-repeat: initial;
       position: fixed;
       min-width: 0px;
       max-width: none;
       min-height: 0px;
       max-height: none;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       left: 0px;
       top: 0px;
       }
```

This will make the video occupy the full screen assuming you are using a standard embedded iframe!